# How to generate a code as C00001,C00002

Tags: javascript

How can I generate a code as C00001,C00002...so on?  My code:

```
 var lastVal = 'C00000'; 
 lastVal=parseInt(lastVal.substring(1,5));
 var nextcust = "C" + zeroize(lastVal,5);

function zeroize( num,  size)
{  
 var snum = "000000" + num;
 var n = snum.toString().length - size;
 console.log( snum.substring(n));
 return snum.substring(n);

}
```

does not work properly.

Comment: When you say it 'does not work properly', what do you mean?  Does it generate the wrong output?  Does it throw an exception?

Comment: its generates output but doesnot increment the value.its just to increment the lastVal variable     lastVal++; it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4jnaR/)

```
var lastVal = "C00000"; 
var nextcust = addNum(lastVal,5);
function addNum(num,size) {  
  var snum = parseInt(num.substring(1),10)+size;
  return "C"+("00000"+snum).slice(-5);
}
```

If you need to just increment by one, use

```
var nextcust = addNum(lastVal,1) ;
```